# Рамка вокруг обтекающего текста

Tags: javascript, css, html5, layout

Можно ли сделать обводку вокруг текста, так чтобы в первом случае она была `_|`-образной, а во втором случае как обычный прямоугльник? К размерам текста и блоков и расположению не стоит привязываться, выставил просто для наглядности. Завтра картинка может быть и ниже и справа или вообще отсутсвовать - это неважно. Блоков с картинкой в ряду может быть и 2 и 3, большее кол-во не предполагается. В целом нужно чтобы как и текст, рамка тоже обтекала

```css
.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
</div>
```

Примерно так должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень желательно, чтобы решение было на чистом CSS. Если надо структруру HTML можете менять на своё усмотрение, главное отображение и что картинка - это отдельный от текста блок

## UPD

В поисках решения наткнулся на такой интересный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706229/13349770), но к сожалению из-за того что используются строчные элементы, то рамка очень сильно искажается в зависимости от размера слова и если начать сужать, то в какой-то момент происходит разрыв между словами и рамка делится на 2 части:

```css
.message {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.wrapped {
   outline: 2px solid black;
}

.wrapped span {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="message">
    <span class="wrapped">
      <span>This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="img right">IMG</div>
  <div class="message">
    <span class="wrapped">
      <span>This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal box round the span
      </span>
    </span>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если в последний пример добавить `text-align: justify` в .message, рамка будет выглядеть лучше

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Чёрт подери, как-же всё просто было... Единственное текст делится на 2 части при очень маленьких экранах, но думаю на это я могу закрыть глаза))) Не буду менять вопрос, пишите как ответ и я его приму

Comment: Это хорошо, если выравнивание текста "по ширине" вас устраивает, хотя в вебе редко используется. Ну и последняя строчка-ступенька в блоке подводит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне удалось что-то нашаманить. Идея в том, чтобы отступ между текстовыми блоками задавать не с помощью margin, а отдельным блоком, который "разрывает" границу _|, ложась поверх.

```css
:root {
  --text-pad: 8px;
  --border-size: 2px;
  --border: var(--border-size) solid green;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;

  border-right: var(--border);
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  
  margin-right: var(--text-pad);
  padding: 0 var(--text-pad) var(--text-pad) 0;
  background: white;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: var(--border);
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  padding: 0 var(--text-pad);
  background: white;
  border: var(--border);
}

.container { padding: 10px; }

.offset {
  padding: calc(var(--text-pad) / 2) 0px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-left">
    <div class="img">IMG</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
  <div class="offset"></div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita,
    facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
  <div class="offset"></div>
</div>
```

Тут есть пограничный случай, когда оба текстовых блока меньше по высоте, чем изображение. Но и с этим можно пошаманить...

---

**UPD**
Код выше годится для частного случая. Учитывая все пожелания, перспективы подхода туманны.

В вашем примере, как уже было отмечено, можно улучшить результат, добавив `text-align: justify` в класс `.message`.

---

Также хочу поделится решением на базе Canvas и JS. Я сначала всерьез не рассматривал такой вариант, но удалось получить достаточно эффективное решение.

Метод [`clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) помогает сымитировать булевы операции над прямоугольными областями элементов. Т.е. все текстовые блоки используем как области отсечения, рисуем поверх рамки блоков-картинок, затем их же залитыми без рамки, чтобы затереть лишние линии внутри группы.

```js
const canvas    = document.getElementById('outline');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const txtBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
const lImages   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-left');
const rImages   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-right');
const ctx       = canvas.getContext('2d');

let lineSize = 2;

function drawOutline() {
  const rc = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  canvas.width = rc.width;
  canvas.height = rc.height;

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2 * lineSize;

  for (tb of txtBlocks) {
    ctx.rect(tb.offsetLeft, tb.offsetTop, tb.offsetWidth, tb.offsetHeight);
  }

  ctx.clip();

  drawComponents(rImages, true);
  drawComponents(lImages, true);
  ctx.stroke();

  drawComponents(lImages, false);
  drawComponents(rImages, false);
}

function drawComponents(rects, stroke) {
  let left = rects[0].classList.contains('img-left');

  for (im of rects) {
    let l = left ? 0 : im.offsetLeft;
    let w = left ? im.offsetLeft + im.offsetWidth : canvas.width - l + im.offsetWidth;

    if (stroke)
      ctx.rect(l, im.offsetTop, w, im.offsetHeight);
    else
      ctx.fillRect(l, im.offsetTop, w, im.offsetHeight);
  }
}

drawOutline();
window.addEventListener('resize', drawOutline);
//
```

```css
:root {
  --text-pad: 8px;
}

#outline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;  
  margin-right: var(--text-pad);
  padding: var(--text-pad);
  padding-left: 0;
}

.img-right {
  float: right; 
  margin-left: var(--text-pad);
  padding:  var(--text-pad);
  padding-right: 0;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.small { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
.medium { height: 80px; width: 80px; }

.img-left+.img-left {
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--text-pad));
}
.img-right+.img-right {
  margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--text-pad));
}

.text {
  padding: 0 var(--text-pad);
  margin-top: var(--text-pad);
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="outline"></canvas>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
</canvas>
```

Решение, кажется, универсальным. Можно добавить любой набор картинок с разным позиционированием. Текстовые блоки могут разбиваться на несколько изолированных.

Остается две проблемы. Первая – это формирование пустых блоков. Но я не представляю как понять, что текста уже нет. Вторая – это формирование лишних узких полосок. К счастью, есть простое решение. Вводим переменную tolerance и проверяем расстояние от нижней границы рисуемого блока до нижней границы текстового блока. Если расстояние <= tolerance, то рисуем до нижней границы текстового блока, затирая полоску.

```js
const canvas    = document.getElementById('outline');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const txtBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
const lImages   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-left');
const rImages   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-right');
const ctx       = canvas.getContext('2d');

let lineSize = 2;
let tolerance = 18;
let toleranceLines = [];

function drawOutline() {
  const rc = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  canvas.width = rc.width;
  canvas.height = rc.height;

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2 * lineSize;
  toleranceLines = [];

  for (tb of txtBlocks) {
    ctx.rect(tb.offsetLeft, tb.offsetTop, tb.offsetWidth, tb.offsetHeight);
    toleranceLines.push(tb.offsetTop + tb.offsetHeight);
  }

  ctx.clip();

  drawComponents(rImages, true);
  drawComponents(lImages, true);
  ctx.stroke();

  drawComponents(lImages, false);
  drawComponents(rImages, false);
}

function drawComponents(rects, stroke) {
  let left = rects[0].classList.contains('img-left');

  for (im of rects) {
    let l = left ? 0 : im.offsetLeft;
    let w = left ? im.offsetLeft + im.offsetWidth : canvas.width - l + im.offsetWidth;
    let h = im.offsetHeight;
    let b = im.offsetTop + h;

    let i = toleranceLines.findIndex((v) => Math.abs(b - v) <= tolerance);
    if (i !== -1) h += toleranceLines[i] - b;

    if (stroke)
      ctx.rect(l, im.offsetTop, w, h);
    else
      ctx.fillRect(l, im.offsetTop, w, h);
  }
}

drawOutline();
window.addEventListener('resize', drawOutline);
```

```css
:root {
  --text-pad: 8px;
}

#outline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;  
  margin-right: var(--text-pad);
  padding: var(--text-pad);
  padding-left: 0;
}

.img-right {
  float: right; 
  margin-left: var(--text-pad);
  padding:  var(--text-pad);
  padding-right: 0;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.small { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
.medium { height: 80px; width: 80px; }

.img-left+.img-left {
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--text-pad));
}
.img-right+.img-right {
  margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--text-pad));
}

.text {
  padding: 0 var(--text-pad);
  margin-top: var(--text-pad);
}

.container {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="outline"></canvas>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
  <div class="img-left"><div class="img medium">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="img-right"><div class="img small">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
</canvas>
```

Понятно, что tolerance не должен превышать высоту строки текста, иначе будут артефакты.

Теоретически, если оперировать полигонами, а не рисованием на канве, можно частично порешать первую проблему при `overflow-wrap: anywhere`, или предварительном анализе текста, чтобы с определенной долей вероятности можно было определить, что блок пуст. Но до этого руки пока не дошли.

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь будет полезно.

Comment: О! Уже намного лучше :) Но у вас тоже всё завязано на том, где конкретно находится блок с картинкой. И в случае когда сообщение чуть больше чем блок с картинкой то появляется пустая тонкая линия https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ADHp.png. Кстати забыл упомянуть, что блоков с картинкой в ряду может быть и 2 и 3 большее кол-во не предполагается. Шас в вопрос тоже добавлю

Comment: Обновил вопрос, может поможет вам эта идея и вы сможете помочь мне :)

Comment: По поводу пустой тонкой линии. Это не является артефактом, блок целостный. Ведь мы решаем задачу не обтекания картинки текстом (это и так происходит), а обтекание блоком. В этом смысле, поведение логичное. Хотя я понял ваши пожелания совместить это.
Что касается расположения блока с картинкой, вам же в любом случае прописывать CSS для картинки (float:left или right). А значит дополнительно указать с какой стороны бордюры - не проблема. Про несколько картинок в ряд, вопрос, они могут быть разных размеров? Т.е. потенциально может быть двойное обтекание, типа ступеньками?

Comment: На счёт рамки, согласен, можно и самому выставить рамки картинки. Вы убежали вперёд, я хотел это как второй вопрос задать)) Но вообще да, может быть, что в первом ряду 2 блока, во втором ряду 1 блок и текст, должен обтекать оба. После этого мне нужно будет обтекание при скроллинге (но думаю не будем так вперёд убегать) :)

Comment: Спасибо за обновление и новые варианты :) Я, конечно, не хотел задействовать JS, но похоже по другому вариантов нет. На счёт канваса даже не думал, надо будет поиграться

Comment: @EzioMercer Я сначала хотел SVG, но нужно осуществить булевы операции над прямоугольниками. В данном случае, задача проще, чем общая, но времячко углубиться не нашлось. Да там будет уже и без разницы, как выводить полигоны, SVG или Canvas. Как я выше отметил, при таком подходе можно будет добиться лучших результатов. Гипотетически.

Answer (score 2):

Рамку многоугольную сделать - тот еще геморрой. Зато можно симулировать нужное поведение с помощью неразмытых теней:

```css
.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 5px #fff, 6px 6px 0 6px #000;
  margin: 0 calc(12px + 0.5em) 12px 0;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita,
    facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Accusamus expedita, facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus expedita,
    facilis, hic id ipsa ipsam laboriosam libero mollitia nam odio possimus recusandae sed similique tempore unde veniam vitae voluptatem voluptates.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольное решение, возьму на заметку, для других случаев :) Но к сожалению это не решает мою нынешнюю проблему т.к. если первый текст будет размером в 1 слово, то вёрстка рушится. Это просто первый тест-кейс что пришёл в голову, я потому и писал, что к размеру текста не надо привязываться. Надеюсь у вас получится исправить это :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос, может поможет вам эта идея и вы сможете помочь мне :)

Comment: если первый текст будет в одно слово, то да. Лучше тогда минимальную высоту ему задавать правильную. Или обернуть все абзацы в контейнер ,к которому и применять бордер. Плюс блоку .img белый фон задать. 
Решение не абсолютное, да. Но порой проще сделать такое вот и просто ограничить входные данные так, чтобы не было условий для некрасивого результата.